# How to create a common static focusable window in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, transliteration, jwindow

I am creating a Transliterating tool in Java. It's almost complete.
Here is the screenshot.

[image]

I am using `JWindow` for dropdown, **which must be focusable for some reason**.
As, user can write in one input only at one time. I've created this `window` static, so all Text components use the same instance instead of creating new one.

Problem occurs, when I work in more than one window. It works fine unless both window are showing on screen. But when owner window of this dropdown window is closed, dropdown window is not focusable anymore.

As Javadoc of `JWindow(Window owner)` constructor says:

> Creates a window with the specified owner window. This window will not be focusable unless its owner is showing on the screen. If owner is null, the shared owner will be used and this window will not be focusable.

So, how can I create a **static**, **focusable** window, that is shared by all components in different windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a JWindow.

Instead you can use a non decorated JDialog. Then you won't have the focus problem.

Edit:

You can prevent the dialog from initially getting focus when you make it visible by using code like:

```
dialog.setWindowFocusableState(false);
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.setWindowFocusableState(true);
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to work. When I entered text in `JTextField` window shows for a fraction of millisecond, and textfield looses focus.

Comment: It's because I've programmed it to abort transliteration when `JTextField` looses focus! Probably, it was working fine with `JWindow` but not with `JDialog`. `JDialog` must have taken focus from `JTextField`.

Comment: `JDialog must have taken focus from JTextField` - yes, you said you wanted a focusable window. So I'm confused? See edit. Maybe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, got it working in multiple windows by those commands and a little change in my code. Had to call `dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true)` also. But another issue arises. When dropdown window is focused, it is shown as another window in Windows taskbar. Screenshot: http://puu.sh/gXeZ2/7064127152.jpg

Comment: Oh no, my bad, I was using `JDialog((Window) null)` instead of `JDialog()` constructor.